# How to make a PDF readonly without password

Tags: pdf, copy-protection

I have no Acrobat and need to make users access the PDF without using password, but prevent them from copying the PDF(the file itself and the content).

I tried many online *PDF LOCKER* things, but it can't restrict copying the PDF.

I wish downloading Acrobat free trial is not the only option.

Comment: As user meneldal answered, you can't prevent the file from being "copied" if you want people to "view" it .. the act of "viewing" a digital file IS "copying" it, no matter the program .. if I can see the image on my monitor I can capture it (yes, I can even "grab" a movie from Netflix with the right software) .. that being said; what are you specifically trying to hinder your audience from doing? If it's just a 'form' then why wouldn't you want them to 'copy' it? If it's an 'ebook' type thing, then how are you distributing it such that you need the type of restriction you ask for? ..

Comment: txtechhelp// I was asked this question and thought may not possible but couldn't make sure. So I asked here for sure. Thanks anyway. Your comment was helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is you can't actually prevent a PDF from being copied or modified. Adobe software might follow the rules but other programs might not.

If you want to let people see the content of your PDF they will be able to do what they want with it if they try enough. Many PDF readers for example ignore the "no printing" flag.

Comment: Some google results say "PDF/A" is read-only. Is it true that I cannot copy PDF/A file with PDF reader? (except the "many other PDF readers"..)

Comment: For software to display the PDF they have to be able to read it so it means you can make a copy. As far as I know the only way you can make text truly uncopyable is to transform the PDF in a list of images and even then you could OCR it

Comment: @meneldal, and don't forget the trusty 'print screen/paste-to-paint' option to grab the screen (though for some DRM'd content 'print screen' doesn't work, though there's software ways to even get around that ... turtles all the way down)

Comment: There's always what is called the "analog loophole" as long as you let people see the file in the first place so it's more or less useless to try, you will just make it harder for some users but if they really want to they can get around.